# stream_socket_client is failing

Tags: php, sockets

I am building a Drupal site and as part of it I need to grab content from Facebook, Twitter and YouTube using the Aggregator and Media modules. However I can't grab the content because both of these modules call the drupal_http_request function which uses the PHP stream_socket_client function which tries to open a connection to a remote socket.

For example, when I try to grab YouTube content it uses `tcp://gdata.youtube.com:80` when trying to open a connection to YouTube. This is returning FALSE when I am building the site on university computers, yet when I am on my home machine it works fine.

Any ideas why it is not working? It seems strange as obviously the college computers can access the internet.

Btw, IRC does not work for me either...

Answer (score 0):

`stream_socket_client` has `errno` and `errstr` parameters, which should be able to give you some more information about why it is failing.

If I had to guess what the problem is, your university probably has a strict firewall that denies access to most ports, such as the IRC one. Possibly it has an HTTP proxy that must be used by all students. It is possible to set an HTTP proxy for a stream socket by using a stream context.

- [Stream socket options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)
- [Example of stream context proxy options](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Util/StreamContextFactory.php)